# Meteor Collection.find() blocks the entire application during working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I try to display a loading alert on Meteor with modal package during loading of data.

```
'change .filterPieChart': function(evt){

    Modal.show('loadingModal');

    /* a little bit of work */
    var data = MyCollection.find().fetch(); // takes 3 or 4 seconds
    /* lot of work */

    Modal.hide('loadingModal');
}
```

Normally, the alert is displayed at the beginning of the function, and disappears at the end. But here, the alert appears only after the loading time of the MyCollection.find(), and then disappears just behind. How to display it at the beginning of the function ??

I tried to replace Modal.show with reactive variable, and the result is the same, the changing value of reactive variable is detect at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, what probably happens is that the JS engine is busy doing your computation (searching through the collection), and indeed blocks the UI, whether your other reactive variable has already been detected or not.

A simple workaround would be to give some time for the UI to show your modal by delaying the collection search (or any other intensive computation), typically with a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```js
Modal.show('loadingModal');

setTimeout(function () {
    /* a little bit of work */
    var data = MyCollection.find().fetch(); // takes 3 or 4 seconds
    /* lot of work */

    Modal.hide('loadingModal');
}, 500); // delay in ms
```

A more complex approach could be to decrease the delay to the bare minimum by using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Ok thanks it works. But it don't really understand how use requestAnimationFrame in my case. When i am suppose to call it?

Comment: I can't for example, use a new thread on MyCollection.find(), and hide the alert on a callback?

Comment: Unfortunately JS in single threaded, unless you start using [_web workers_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). As for `requestAnimationFrame`, you might need to use it twice to make sure a full frame has been painted. But if your modal showing uses some animation, that may interfere, so you might rather need to use a fix delay (as shown in the above answer), or an event when the modal has finished to appear.

Comment: Yes my modal showing uses animation. It looks little bit hacky, but it works .. It's pity to loose 1/2 second. anyway, thank you, if you think to a better solution, don't hesitate to update your answer

Comment: It always sounds bad I agree, but still better than letting your visitor think your site has crashed. Feedback has some price…

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use template level subscription + reactiveVar. It is more the meteor way and your code looks consistent. As i can see you do some additional work ( retrive some data ) on the `change` event. Make sense to actually really retrive the data on the event instead of simulation this.

```
  Template.TemplateName.onCreated(function () {
    this.subsVar = new RelativeVar();
    this.autorun( () => {
      let subsVar = this.subsVar.get();
      this.subscribe('publicationsName', this.subsVar);    
    })
  })

  Template.TemplateName.events({
    'change .filterPieChart': function(evt){
      Template.instance().collectionDate.subsVar.set('value');
      Modal.show('loadingModal');

      MyCollection.find().fetch();    

      Modal.hide('loadingModal');
    }
  })
```

Please pay attention that i didn't test this code. And you need to use the es6 arrow function.